# Should other devices be required to login again after an email change in settings?

Tags: web-application, session-management

I have had multiple security researchers tell me that the best practice when a user changes their email in settings is to logout all other devices and force them to login again.

Nobody has been able to explain what attack this prevents or how this helps protect users.

### On password changes:

- I require re-entry of the password

  - If an attacker has a stolen session cookie, they shouldn't be able to change the password.
- I **do** force all other devices to login again

  - If an attacker knows a victim's username/password and a victim changes their password, we don't want the attacker to remain logged into the victim's account.
  - If the attacker has a stolen session cookie, we want it to invalidate it.

### On email changes:

- I require re-entry of the password

  - If an attacker has a stolen session cookie, they shouldn't be able to change the email.
- I  invalidate any tokens sent to an email (eg. password reset links).

  - If a user changes their email because an attacker has gained access to their old email, we don't want the attacker to be able to use any previously sent email tokens.

If I force all other devices to login again after changing the email. What scenario is this helping protect against?

Comment: Seems like it *could* make a difference, but it depends on the details of your system. Does it use email as a user name? Does it use email as part of a second factor authentication mechanism or as a means of resetting the password?

Comment: Email and username are separate. You can't log in with an email address. Two-factor is TOTP only currently. WebAuthn passwordless in testing for future authentication. Emails are only used as password recovery and account alerts / transactional emails.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out the context you are talking about, i.e. that the user itself has changed their email in the settings of your web application. I've changed your question to make this context more clear. Hope I got this context correct.

Comment: You should require the user to re-enter their password when changing e-mail or password.  That would start a new session.  This is to prevent a stolen session from taking control of the account.  Remember that a stolen session is not the same as stolen e-mail/password combination.  Most sessions are persisted via token these days... or possibly a hash of password for older sites with "remember me" type cookies.

Comment: @pcalkins I already require the password to be re-entered to change the email or password. I have tried to clarify the question to reduce confusion.

Comment: so it's just helping in the more common situation where a session is stolen.  This logs out the attacker as quickly as possible.  If the attacker knows the email/password, then you could be logging out the victim instead... 2fa to cell might take care of that 'cept for sim-swaps.   You can't guard against all thefts, but protecting against session theft is probably the most important.

Comment: this also might be very necessary depending on how secure your authentication is... rogue sessions might be kept indefinitely with refresh tokens if you trust multiple sessions just based on "claims".  You might want to include exactly what kind of session/tokens are used here.